# How to install Manjaro termnila in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line

I like the Manjaro terminal and i want it for my Ubuntu 20.04. Somebody now how to install it? Actually I have gnome terminal.

Comment: What is Manjaro terminal? Do you have screenshot or some link to it?

Comment: There you have an example [Manjaro](https://forum.manjaro.org/uploads/default/original/3X/5/3/53d98f7b05505d5627197cebf9f949ecc2b4432f.jpeg)

Comment: Download the source for "Manjaro terminal". Create a Ubuntu software build environment (`sudo apt install build-essential`). Find the dependencies of "Manjaro terminal". "Port" the whole mess to Ubuntu.